# Best way to store mix of large and small files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, storage, gridfs

I am developing asp net mvc core application in which working with many small and large files. I hear, that i can to store large files (> 16 mb) in MongoDb GridFs, but i have many files smaller then 16 mb too. Please, help me choose the better way for storing files.

Should I use a combination of the following approaches:

1. Store large files in the MongoDb Gridfs
2. Store small files in disk, in filesystem

If i choose this combination, in the code, I will have 2 services that work differently with files (depending on the size). Is it right solution?

Comment: have a look at [this library](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/File-Storage.html) for an easier/unified solution for file storage in mongo. disclaimer: i'm the author